# Copying image with text from Microsoft Teams Chat into Word or Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, images, copy-paste, microsoft-teams

It appears:  It's really hard to copy from Microsoft teams chat to either a word doc or an email (sometimes I even use notepad as an intermediary) and it's next to impossible to copy all of a text + image + text + image stream cleanly....

I can do a control-A and select all which gets the text and many icons but not real images, and I actually have better results pasting this in notepad and then in word or outlook as opposed to using word or outlook directly.

Does anyone have a good way of copying Teams chats especially if they contain both text and real images (i.e. ones more complicated than icons / emoticons).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it seems that there is no such way to copy all the Teams chat content containing images completely to the messages in Outlook client.

If there are not many images in your Teams chat content, it is recommended that you could try to right-click the images in Teams to copy and manually add it to the place where you failed to paste the image in the Outlook message.

[image]

In addition, I found that when manually selecting part of Teams chat content, the content containing image can be copied and pasted successfully. If you don't have to copy and paste all Teams chat content, maybe this can help you.

[image]

[image]